# How to export a database we have a connection to?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a connection to a database. I would like to export a database. I have tried using the SQL Import and Export wizard but it says that `the ConnectionString is invalid`.

I then clicked on tasks and generated a script to extract all of the schema and data, so I ended up with a .sql file.

I don't know how to open this .sql file or if this is even the database, as I just generated a script. Please guide me to what I did.

Comment: a sql file is only a text file, so if it is not too big, every texteditor can open it or even the ssms.  Why is this tagged mysql?

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL Server *and* MySQL..?

Comment: I didn't mean to tag mysql. Not sure why it showed up there.

Answer (score 0):

.sql format is text format, any text editor should be able to open it. Also, Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS) should be able to open it.

Comment: It says "The specified file cannot be found" when I try to upload it." It's a script meant to create a database.